# How to delete a UIView Object from screen?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have created a sample app where i have created some class inherited from `NSObject` class for defining different atributes and properties of my object . Now i have a subclass a `UIView` and also able to show that object in my iphone screen.

Now i have a problem whenever i want to delete a triangle i generally call `[self removeFromSuperview];`and it remove the view from my screen.

But it is just removing the view from screen not completely deleting the object.

How can i delete the object completely?

Comment: send release message to object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gather from your description - how about:

```
[self removeFromSuperview];
[self release];
```

Does that work?  Alternatively, you should put this kind of logic in your view controller.  Then, is you have a reference to object (say, myObject), then use:

```
[myObject removeFromSuperview];
[myObject release];
```

Removing from the super view does not mean delete this object.  Your object can very live without being connected to a UIView hierarchy.

EDIT: (to flesh out Peter Deweese's comment)

When you create an UIView you can do this:

```
MyView* view = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:myViewRect];
[mySuperView addChild:view];
[view release];
```

This means that you no long own the view, but the super view does.  The super view retains your view when its added as a child, and you relinquish it with release.  Later, when you do:

```
[self removeFromSuperview];
```

The retain count will drop to 0 and your object will be deleted automatically.

Good idea Peter!

Comment: And unless it was retained by you, you won't even need to release it.  When added to the superview it is retained and when removed it is released.

Comment: Peter, I edited my above answer to integrate your answer.  If I could upvote comments I would :)